# \endframe error when using \textrm in Beamer

Tags: beamer, compiling

I have been using Beamer to write a presentation and have found strange behaviour when using `\textrm` in the `equation` environment.

I write the following:

```
\begin{frame}{Individual Wealth Processes}
We propose the stochastic differential equation
\begin{equation*}
\dmath X^i(t) = \mu \dmath t + \sigma\rho \dmath W^\textrm{M}(t) + \sigma \sqrt{ 1 - \rho^2} \dmath W^{i}(t)
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
```

but I get the error message `missing { inserted. \end{frame}` and `missing } inserted. \end{frame}`. However, the code compiles normally when I change the `textrm` for `texttt`, and so it seems the `textrm` is the source of my problems.

I have the following preamble which is copied from a prior document which I am basing my presentation on, which I would like to keep so I can easily copy tables, figures, equations, etc. I have made some small modifications to make the presentation beamer friendly

```
\documentclass[hyperref={colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue}]{beamer}
\input{presentation_preamble}
\begin{document}
% ... begin frame etc ...
\end{document}
```

where `presentation_preamble` contains:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash,figurewithin=section,tablewithin=section]{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}    
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Ensures the first paragraphs are indented.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern} % load a font with all the characters
%\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{parskip} % Gives nicer indenting.
\usepackage{pgf}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\newcommand{\dmath}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

%\makeindex

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\justifying
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}

%\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=7 % Supresses old PDF version warnings
\hbadness=10000 % Supresses bad box warnings
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

% Gives the nicer SQRT symbol.
\usepackage{letltxmacro} 
\makeatletter
\let\oldr@@t\r@@t
\def\r@@t#1#2{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{$\oldr@@t#1{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht0
    \advance\dimen0-0.2\ht0
    \setbox2=\hbox{\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
    {\box0\lower0.4pt\box2}}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt}
\renewcommand*{\sqrt}[2][\ ]{\oldsqrt[#1]{#2}}
\makeatother

%\setlength{\parindent}{15mm}
% Hopefully this avoids words being hyphenated
\pretolerance=10000
\tolerance=2000 
\emergencystretch=10pt
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Placing curly braces around it should work, like this:`W^{\textrm{M}}(t)`

Comment: Why do you use \textrm instead of \mathrm?

Comment: @RunarTrollet , That does work for a short term solution (so thanks), but I have loads of equations that I would like to copy and paste, and manually placing `{}` around them all by hand is not a feasible solution. Any suggestions on how to circumnavigate the issue?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , an old bad habit from when I wanted to use it to input superscripts and subscripts for words in maths mode.

Comment: Well bad habits are sometimes punished. beamer redefines \textrm. Besides this is it is also not a good habit to avoid braces around superscripts. While `W^\mathrm{M}` will work, `W^{...}` is better unless the superscript is really only a single char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

beamer redefines `\textrm` and so it breaks when you use it directly as subscript. You need to put braces around it, or better use `\mathrm`. While `\mathrm` would work without braces it is imho better to get used to add them anyway.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Individual Wealth Processes}
We propose the stochastic differential equation
\begin{equation*}
%W^\textrm{M}(t) %breaks
W^{\mathrm{M}}(t) 
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```